# my code for storing a high score when the game is closed isn't working. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#

My game has a start screen and a game screen. I want the highscore to be written on the start screen and then updated if the high score is beaten. this all works fine until i x out of the game then it is reset.

I created a variable called HighScore in the Application Settings. i set it to 0. i print this on the start screen and update it after the game is played before the game screen is closed and the player is returned to the start screen.

this is the code where the highscore is tested against the current score (playtime). this is also where the game terminates and player is returned to start screen by pressing enter. i dont know where the code would be for what happens when the game is x-ed out.

```
 if (playtime> Properties.Settings.Default.HighScore)
                    {
                        Properties.Settings.Default.HighScore = playtime;
                    }
```

i expected the highscore to be retained when the game is closed but it isnt.

Comment: Call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure how App settings work, but one idea to store information after closing is with a simple write-read function:

```cs
using System.IO;
public float ReadHighScore(){
var r = new StreamReader("./SaveData.txt");
var d = r.ReadLine();
var val = float.Parse(d);
return val;

} 
public void WriteHighScore(){
var w = new StreamWriter("./SaveData.txt");
w.WriteLine(HighScore);
}
```

This is a good way to save some data after runtime, as the files will persist anyways.